# Aspose PDF memory leak issue

Tags: pdf, aspose, aspose.words

We are using *Aspose PDF* and are facing the following issues which are sort of show stopper:

1. Aspose PDF is not releasing memory. we have set object to null but they do not release memory.  Result - in my web service after 20-30 calls, server memory is 100% used, and they start creating timeouts.

   -- we are trying to resolve with aspose support team - but no concrete reply since last 2 weeks.
2. When we convert PDF to txt or HTML - this adds lot of special characters which are not recognized by our scripts.

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: What did Aspose support team say?

Comment: Aspose team agreed to this memory leak, but for fix, they say -- we will get back to you shortly. And its been more than week with same answer.  ;)

Comment: @Bob - this is their latest reply  - As said, now product teams are investigating the issue, please spare us little more time for proper investigation. We will get back to you at earliest possible.

Comment: I guess in such a case you might not be able to find someone who can solve the issue. I mean if support team don't know what to do then probably no one else does.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue with large PDFs, after Aspose has run it isn't freeing up memory and a 16MB PDF is eating 2.5GB of RAM during processing. I also have a 11MB PDF that fails to open and slowly ate up 15GB of RAM before I had to kill the process. I notice the date on this thread so wondering if you ever got a resolution?

Answer (score 5):

just stumbled over this post while looking for a solution to a memory leak problem of my own, although this one is found within their Slides library, used for interacting with Powerpoint files. Not sure what language you're using, but this was eventually how we resolved it using .NET.

After little help from the Aspose team, we finally found that the easiest way to handle this was using a seperate AppDomain for the offending code. This has a slight performance impact, but it's only a few seconds at most so we deemed this to be acceptable. This means that after we're done, we can just call AppDomain.Unload(*variable*) and it will close everything down and purge the memory and this solved all the issues, we saw the memory leaking and then after the unloading occured, we saw everything released. Hope this helps!

Comment: I know it was a long time ago but I don't suppose you have any more info on this or even better, some example code?

Comment: "we finally found that the easiest way to handle this[...]" That of course is the *easiest way for Aspose*: Let their users create a workaround. However, a real fix would be nice because it is 2021 and the issue still exists.

Comment: I'm afraid not, the project that was using Aspose has long since been mothballed now, but there have most likely been multiple new versions since then so it could very well be fixed.